# Composting cooked food

Tags: compost

I’ve made some vegetable broth and after it’s done I’m left over with some boiled vegetables can those be composted? I’ve seen some articles that say you cannot compost them while others you can which would be best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have to be treated the same way as "greens", i.e. must be balanced with "browns" like straw and dead leaves. There are two factors to take into account:

1- **SALT** - Number one enemy for the plant. Too salty is not good for them.

2- Cooked food is more mushy. That means that too much of it will tend to compact more quickly and turn your compost pile into anaerobic composting which is less effective than aerobic (thermophyllic), takes longer, makes odors and leaches out quite alot.

It is advised to add more browns than usual. Too much brown is better than too much green. I have a compost pile which is mostly fallen leaves from a nearby tree, and trimmings from my garden. It composts well when wetted. with just some greens and it starts to heat-up as well.